# how to make report on memory and cpu utilization

Tags: jmeter

Actually currently I working on performance testing using JMeter  and I want to find memory utilization and CPU utilization here I use perfmon plugin and now generate report for memory utilization and CPU utilization so help for how to generate report ?

Comment: Here is a blog with step-by-step instructions: https://knowledgeworldforyou.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/jmeter-performance-of-cpu-and-memory-usage-using-perfmon-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate charts images out of the [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) listener output file using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

1. Configure the PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to store the values into .jtl results file, as per [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/#Non-GUI-Mode):

   > If you run JMeter in non GUI mode and want to save monitoring data to file, just configure result file saving in GUI as you do with other listeners. After running the test you may load saved file into GUI and see the values timeline.

   [image]
2. Once done you can create the image from the .jtl file:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png perfmon.png --input-jtl perfmon.jtl --plugin-type PerfMon
   ```

   and you will get the image with your charts:

   [image]